# Flutter TabBar height Icons

Tags: flutter, height, tabbar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestTab extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
   Tab(
    child: Image.asset(
      'assets/icons/project/proj_001.png',
    ),
  ),
 ...
  Tab(
    icon: Image.asset(
      'assets/icons/project/all.png',
      height: 100,
    ),
  ),
 ...
  Tab(
    icon: Image.asset(
      'assets/icons/project/proj_009.png',
    ),
  ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 5,
      length: myTabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(150.0),
          child: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: myTabs,
          ),
        ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                'Test',
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I try to increase the icon height, but it doesn't work. It's as if he selects all the parameters himself. Does not allow reducing the width or increasing the height of elements.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQaYY.png)

Please tell me how you can increase the height of elements?

Answer (score 0):

if u want set the icon size small then u can do like that

```
         Tab(
              text: "Category List",
              icon: Icon(Icons.home,size: 15,),
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Product List",
              icon: Icon(Icons.view_list,size: 15,),
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Contact Us",
              icon: Icon(Icons.contacts,size: 15,),
            ),
            Tab(
              text: "Darshan Timing",
              icon: Icon(Icons.access_time,size: 15,),
            )
```

here `size: 15,` will make the icon size as you want

Answer (score -1):

You gotta make custom TabBar for customization. Something like this.

**CustomTabbar**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChangeTextSizeTabbar extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  ChangeTextSizeTabbarState createState() {
    return new ChangeTextSizeTabbarState();
  }

}

class ChangeTextSizeTabbarState extends State<ChangeTextSizeTabbar> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Change Text Size Tabbar Example"),
          bottom: TabBar(

              tabs: <Tab>[
                Tab(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/icons/project/proj_001.png',
                     height : 100,
                     width : 100,
                  ),
                ),

                Tab(
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    'assets/icons/project/all.png',
                     height : 100,
                     width : 100,
                  ),
                ),

                Tab(
                  icon: Image.asset(
                    'assets/icons/project/proj_009.png',
                     height : 100,
                     width : 100,
                  ),
                ),

              ]          ),
        ),

        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(),
            Container(),
            Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'change_text_size_tabbar_task-3.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            // This is the theme of your application.
            //
            // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
            // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
            // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
            // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
            // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
            // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
            // is not restarted.
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          //home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
          home: ChangeTextSizeTabbar(),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see customization in your example :(

Comment: oh my bad I missed that!

Comment: Excuse me. but I don't see any differences in Your code from mine. All the same. Please specify a specific location that allows you to enable customization.